# Responsive timelines pointers are moving when the screen gets wider

Tags: html, css

I use @media screen to resize the timeline on devices >=700px
when I resize the browser from the smallest size going to the biggest the circles on the timeline are moving to the right side

smallest screen

[image]

a little bit wider

[image]

Source code

```css
/* Timeline Styling */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
    
  /* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */
  .timeline {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  /* The vertical line */
  .timeline::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 6px;
    background-color: #c9c9c9;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -3px;
  }
  
  /* Content container */
  .container {
    padding: 10px 40px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: inherit;
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  /* Small timeline circles */
  .container::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    right: 47.8%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 4px solid #007bff;
    top: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  /* container left align */
  .left {
    left: -32.3%;
  }
  
  
  
  /* pointing left */
  .right::before {
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 30px;
    border: medium solid white;
    border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
  }
  
  
  /*content */
  .content {
    padding: 20px 30px;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 6px;
  }
  
  /*Enable Responsive feature */
  @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  /* Place the timelime to the left */
    .timeline::after {
      left: 10%;
    }

  .container::after {
    left: 7%;
  }

  .container{
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
  
  /* Full-width containers */
    .container {
      width: 100%;
      padding-left: 70px;
      padding-right: 25px;
    }
  
  /* Make sure that all arrows are pointing leftwards */
    .container::before {
      left: 60px;
      border: medium solid white;
      border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
      border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
    }
  
  /* Make sure all circles are at the same spot */
    .left::after, .right::after {
      left: 15px;
    }
  
  }
```

```html
    
<!-- Timeline -->
<div class="timeline">
<div class="container container-left">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>2053</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid doloremque aspernatur maxime fugit autem laborum</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container container-left">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>2053</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid doloremque aspernatur maxime fugit autem laborum</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container container-left">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>2053</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid doloremque aspernatur maxime fugit autem laborum</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

any help?

Comment: I fixed it by adding a min-width rule to the .container . but now the problem is that the .container div became very wide so you need to scroll to read the text . any ideas to resize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
.container::after {
    left: 7%;
}
```

to

```
.container::after {
    left: calc(10% - 16px);
}
```

When you use 10% for the line and 7% for the circles, they aren't fixed relative to each other because as the screen size changes, 1% is worth a different amount of pixels. If you put them in terms of the same percentage and just include an offset to center the circle, it will scale them together.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: I did it in another way and it worked perfectly . I just added min-width:900px; to the container within the media rule and it worked! I had the same problem with the full desktop screen so I decided to the same again but as min-width:auto; . can you tell me the different if you have some time for me ? :)

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate your solution. Does mine work for you as well?